# Generic type as a annotation

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a generic class where i am exposing a no of db related operation like find, findById, save etc. So  have a function like:

```
public <T> T getById(Class<T> type, long id){
        return <some entityManager>.find(type, id);
    }
```

But if you see carefully T type classes  would always be annotated with `@Entity` so how could i put that into my code. for example some thing like:

`Class<? extends Entity>` (i know this is incorrect but wanted to put my point clearly what i want)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you only want to be able to pass `Class` objects for classes annotated with a certain annotation, then the answer is it's impossible. You can't put such a restriction at compile time.

At runtime, you'd have to do the check yourself with reflection, [`Class#getAnnotation(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-).